# Copying row based on cell value slowing down excel

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code that I am using to copy rows from a sheet call "Active Job Report" to a new sheet Labeled by a persons name. It is looking for the persons name in Column D and then copying all the rows to the Sheet labeled by that persons name. This is just for one person, and I currently just copied and changed names for the other sheets.

I have 9 different sheets (The different people that have ordered) that information is getting copied to. I have basic VBA knowledge, so I am wondering if there is a more efficient way, or if I can copy the code for each persons name to copy the rows. It seems like the file runs really slow with this.

I want to tie all of this into a current macro that is pulling data from a software database into excel. If this is unclear I will update with information needed.

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDestin As Worksheet
Dim lngDestinRow As Long
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngCel As Range

' Shane Love
Set wsSource = Sheets("Active Job Report")     'Edit "Sheet1" to your source sheet name
Set wsDestin = Sheets("Shane Love")


Sheets("Shane Love").Cells.ClearContents

With wsSource
    'Following line assumes column headers in Source worksheet so starts at row2
    Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
End With

For Each rngCel In rngSource
    If rngCel.Value = "Shane Love" Then
        With wsDestin
            'Following line assumes column headers in Destination worksheet
            lngDestinRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            rngCel.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wsDestin.Cells(lngDestinRow, "A")
        End With
    End If
Sheets("Shane Love").Select
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Due Date"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Customer"
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Ordered By"
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Job #"
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Part Number"
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "REV"
Range("H1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Description"
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Make QTY"
Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Trnsf QTY"
Range("k1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Cmpltd QTY"
Range("L1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "FRR"
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Current Work Area"
Range("N1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Current OP"
Range("O1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Order Date"
Range("P1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Priority"

Sheets("Shane Love").Select
Columns("Q:S").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
'Columns("P:R").Select
'Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Worksheets("Shane Love").Range("B1:P1").AutoFilter
Worksheets("Shane Love").Columns("A:P").AutoFit


Next rngCel`
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  You're trying to loop through worksheets? Or just how to make this same code run faster/"tighter"?

Comment: Hey Bruce, I just want to make sure that this will run efficient, or if it is going to slow down my excel. I have gotten this to work so that all the data moves to the different worksheets. Seeing if there is anything I can fix to do it better. All I did was copy this code, and repeat it for the 9 different names that would appear in Column D on the Active Job Report

Comment: Do you mean you run the above once, then change this `If rngCel.Value = "Shane Love" Then` to some other name and run the same again. (Do you also change the `Sheets("Shane Love")` references to the new name you're looking for?  Then run again with another new name, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I just copied the same that I have above, and change the rng.cel.value to equal the new name  & the sheets("")

Comment: Do you have a list of the names? That would help. Or, is each sheet one of the names (which I think it's what it sounds like, no?)

Comment: Names are as follows. Rich Baran, Jamie Lorfano, Billy Sharp, Shane Love, Chris Gillin, Dennis Hampton, Jason, Engineering which consists of 3 names (Rick Macgowan, Ross Fletcher, Parker Grove). Then the last tab would be for all the names in column D that don't match any of those names. I will try what you posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this work? I assume that every sheet, except "Active Job Report" are a sheet you want to run the macro on.

```
Sub copyWS()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDestin As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim lngDestinRow As Long, i As Long
Dim rngSource As Range, rngCel As Range
Dim headers() As Variant

headers() = Array("Due Date", "Customer", "Ordered By", "Job #", "Part Number", "REV", "Description", "Make QTY", "Trnsf QTY", _
                  "Cmpltd QTY", "FRR", "Current Work Area", "Current OP", "Order Date", "Priority")
' Shane Love

Set wsSource = Sheets("Active Job Report")    'Edit "Sheet1" to your source sheet name
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> wsSource.Name Then
        With wsSource
            'Following line assumes column headers in Source worksheet so starts at row2
            Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
        End With

        Set wsDestin = Sheets(ws.Name)
        With wsDestin
            .Cells.ClearContents
            For Each rngCel In rngSource
                If rngCel.Value = wsDestin.Name Then
                    'Following line assumes column headers in Destination worksheet
                    lngDestinRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    rngCel.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wsDestin.Cells(lngDestinRow, "A")
                End If
            Next rngCel

            For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
                .Cells(1, i + 2).Value = headers(i)    ' starts with i + 2, because first iteration of i, i=0, so i+2 = 2 (Col. B)
            Next i

            .Columns("Q:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            '.Columns("P:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

            .Range("B1:P1").AutoFilter
            .Columns("A:P").AutoFit
        End With
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Another note is that every time the active job report is refreshed, I would want to make sure that these worksheets would be refreshed. I don't know if there is something to clear the worksheet everytime, but I ran into an error when I tried to run this.

Comment: @D.Schiermeyer - What error? What line did it occur on?

Comment: It is a "Type Mismatch" and it happens on the Headers at the beginning

Comment: @D.Schiermeyer - D'oh!! See my edit, I just change `Dim headers() as String` to `... as Variant`

Comment: The next one I ran into is "object doesn't support this property or method" at line "For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook"

Comment: @D.Schiermeyer *facepalm* sorry, I must have been sleep writing this. Change that to `For each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: That worked well! Thank you. If you saw the list of names I had above, I have two other worksheets that I would like to add. One would be for engineering, which would include the names 3 names. The other would be for everyone else, which would mean if it didn't get added to one of the worksheets, I would want it to display in this worksheet. Is this difficult to add?

Comment: @D.Schiermeyer - I'm not sure what you mean. If you have other worksheets you want to add, as long as they're in the workbook, it should run on them.  You can also specify sheets to run it on by adding `or ws.Name = "engineering"` to this: `If ws.Name <> wsSource.Name Then`, so `If ws.Name <> wsSource.Name or ws.Name = "engineering" Then`...?

Comment: I want to add 3 different names from the Active Job Report Column D to the Engineering worksheet. I got confused how to do that with 3 different criteria. I also want to have a worksheet for the rest of the names in Column D, that didn't go into any of the separate worksheets. Sorry if this is still confusing